# ES6 destructuring with dynamic object properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to know if the following is possible with ES6.

I have an object "o" with method:

```
get(name) { 
}
```

Which returns some other object depending on the provided name.

I have another function test like this:

```
function test(o) {

}
```

I wonder is there any way to destructur the paramaters with calliing get on the object.

For example: ***This is not working - it's the thing i want to do***

```
// here is what I'm trying to do
function test({db: get('db')}) {

}
// this is working
function test(o) {
  var db = o.get('db');
}
```

I want "db" varaible to equal "o.get('db')". I can do it in the function body but I wonder if it's possible to make the it direclty in the argument definition.

So far I can use:

```
let [a, b, c] = [o.get('a'), o.get('b'), o.get('c')];
```

As first line in the function.

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible. Destructuring is used to *unpack* the properties. You cannot *call* a function like `get`.

Comment: I think you should not want this. Makes the code much more complicated.

Comment: You can use getters though

Comment: Are you looking for [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use getters instead of the generic `get` function. This would allow unpacking and also make the rest of the code easier to read:

```js
let SomeObj = {
  get db() {
    return "this is db";
  }
}

function func({db}) {
  console.log('DB', db);
}

func(SomeObj);
```

If your properties are dynamic, you could do a horrible thing like this:

```js
let SomeObj = {
  get(name) {
    return `this is ${name}`;
  }
}

function func(o, {db = o.get('db'), blah = o.get('blah')} = {}) {
  console.log('DB', db);
  console.log('blah', blah);
}

func(SomeObj);
```

but a more realistic option would be to have a function that maps `get` over an array of props:

```js
let SomeObj = {
    get(name) {
        return `this is ${name}`;
    }
}

let extract = (obj, ...props) => props.map(p => obj.get(p));


function func(o) {
    let [db, blah] = extract(o, 'db', 'blah')

    console.log('DB', db);
    console.log('blah', blah);
}

func(SomeObj);
```

Finally, you can wrap your object in a `Proxy` to provide a dynamic getter, in which case simple destructuring will work out of the box:

```js
let SomeObj = new Proxy({}, {
    get(obj, name) {
      if(name in obj)
        return obj[name];
      return `this is ${name}`;
    }
});

function func({db, blah}) {
    console.log('DB', db);
    console.log('blah', blah);
}

func(SomeObj);
```

Comment: Yes, but I cannot pass arguments because get doesnt alllow parameters.
Maybe I will do this as first line in the code: let [a,b] = [o.get('a'), o.get('b'];

Comment: @user2693928: so, your `get` accepts other params beside "name"?

Comment: @user2693928 Just `let a = o.get('a'), b = o.get('b');`. No unnecessary arrays.

Comment: @georg, the params are dynamic, I canno set "db", "test", "prop2" as they are set with method "set" dynamically, so i need "name" argument"